# Differential equation system independent of non-diagonal values of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

> For every $n = 1,2,3, \dots$ we have the matrix $$A_n = \begin{pmatrix} 1& n \\ n&  1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and the following system of differential equations $$y'(t) = A_n y(t)$$ Show that the solution to this system is independent of $n$.

I had this question in an exam. I couldn't think of a solution, and it still bugs me.

Comment: Why don't you solve this for a generic $n$?

Comment: Somehow I question the veracity of this assertion.  Compare the cases $n = 1$ and $n = 100$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of the matrix 
$$
A_n=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & n\\
n & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are the solution to $(1-x)^2=n^2$, or $x=1\pm n$. The eigenvector for eigenvalue $1\pm n$ is $v_\pm =(1,\pm1)^T/\sqrt{2}$. Construct the orthogonal matrix
$$
O=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $O^TA_n O=\mathrm{diag}(1+n, 1-n):=D_n$, so $A_n=OD_n O^T$. Using this and defining $\tilde{y}=O^Ty:=(\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y})^T$, your differential equation turns into
$$ \begin{cases}
\tilde{X}'=(1+n)\tilde{X}\\
\tilde{Y}'=(1-n)\tilde{Y}
\end{cases}\Longrightarrow \tilde{X}=A\exp[(1+n)x], \qquad \tilde{Y}=B\exp[(1-n)x]$$
transforming back
$$
y=O\tilde{y}=\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
Ae^{nx}+Be^{-nx}\\
Ae^{nx}-Be^{-nx}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the solution does indeed depedn on $n$. What you are asked to prove is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, i reached the same answer, but i guessed it was wrong since it couldn't prove the required argument and thought i was missing something.

Comment: I suspect there is a typo in the question for matrix $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y(t)$ is a solution to the equation for more than one $n$, then we must have $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr} y(t) = 0$.  But $\pmatrix{0 & 1\cr 1 & 0\cr} \pmatrix{y_1\cr y_2\cr} = \pmatrix{y_2\cr y_1\cr}$.  So the only such solution is
$y = 0$.